# Cosa sono i "mobili stuccati" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Le calle, rigide sui loro steli – quei fiori così frigidi e chic e *moderni* –, stavano a significare che la baronessa sapeva – oh, se sapeva! – che lì fuori, sui grandi boulevard, impazzava qualcosa che si chiama “il nuovo gusto”, che tanta **mobilia stuccata** avrebbe dovuto andare in soffitta, perché le case alla moda oggi sono rarefatte conchiglie di lacca nera e tappeti chiari – la tinta unita è più facile, non si scivola sul gusto –, ma la baronessa è una tenace marescialla dell'antico, come i suoi tanti cognomi e predicati stanno a ricordare, e non s'arrende con facilità alle aberrazioni del contemporaneo.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stuccare1/) ho letto che *stuccare* un mobile o altri oggetti può significare

> Applicare sulla superficie di un oggetto, con una spatola flessibile, dello stucco per livellarla e renderla uniforme riempiendo i vuoti e gli interstizî, e lisciandola quindi con carta vetrata, come preparazione per la tinteggiatura

ma penso che questo non sia il senso di "mobilia stuccata" nel brano precedente. Sembrano piuttosto mobili decorati in certo modo o in qualche stile che, nei tempi descritti nel libro, non è più alla moda. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono i "mobili stuccati" in questo contesto?

Comment: Secondo me sono esattamente *stuccati* nel senso di restaurati. Si tratta di mobili antichi, che magari hanno dovuto fare uno o due giri di manutenzione, mentre la moda vuole cose più moderne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probabilmente si riferisce a stucchi decorativi (che erano spesso applicati sui mobili di un tempo, non tutte le decorazioni erano infatti risultato di intagli ed intarsi). Lo stucco usato varia in composizione da gessi di varie qualità a paste di legno e cellulose varie inclusa la cartapesta. Le decorazioni a stucco erano a volte coperte in pigmenti a similoro o con foglia d'oro. Se si vuole un esempio la cosa era ancora usata per le cornici ornate del dopoguerra. Un'altra lavorazione che richiede una preparazione a stucco è il metodo "a sandracca" che imita lo stile laccato orientale, di moda agli inizi '800 in Italia, il veneziano era una delle aree che produceva molti di questi mobili.
Alla fine degli anni '20 e negli anni '30 prese piede l'arredamento "razionalista" dove le decorazioni vennero abbandonate e le linee molto più semplificate. Poi venne la guerra ed il dopoguerra portò nuovi cambiamenti.

Dal contesto capirai se i mobili di cui si parla sono "stuccati" per intendere vecchi/antichi e riparati/restaurati o se si tratta di mobili antichi decorati con tecniche a stucco. Non ho letto il libro ma siccome si parla di baronessa non credo che i mobili fossero roba riparata... e se fosse una baronessa decaduta e senza troppo denaro probabilmente non si farebbe riparare i mobili (a meno che non lasci debiti dappertutto).

Edit: visto che hai chiesto una foto come esempio, questa è una foto generica presa dalla rete e mostra una cornice. La lavorazione comunque era la stessa con poche variazioni nella composizione dello stucco (un mobile deve essere un poco più resistente di una cornice). È visibile la parte danneggiata dove lo stucco si è perso e mette in mostra il legno sottostante.
[image]

Comment: Da quello che spiega il libro, non si tratta di una baronessa decaduta, ma di una persona ricca.

Comment: Si può trovare alcuna fotografia da qualche parte?

Comment: @Charo Intendi foto del lavoro in stucco o foto di mobili? Le foto che ho sono in libri di tecniche di restauro ecc che non ho con me al momento dovrei cercare in rete.

Comment: @Charo - questo sito spiega la tecnica: http://www.barbaramaldini.it/portfolio-lavori/mobili-shabby-chic-mobili-decorati-mobili-di-recupero-mobili-decapati/2_pastgliaaxel-2/

Comment: Per quanto riguarda la fotografia, va bene così e anche con quella che ha trovato @Josh61.